# select box option value not getting perfect while generating selectbox dynamically by using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

```
<?php
$res = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
while($data = mysql_fetch_row($res))
{
echo "<option value=".$data[0].">" .$data[0]. "</option>";<br>
} 
?>
```

In this case, supposing `data[0]` has sample data value then inside value only sample is storing. How to get whole value?

I'm calling this file by `$.ajax` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your value isn't enclosed in quotes. You can fix this in two ways.

1:

```
<?php
$res = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
while($data = mysql_fetch_row($res))
{
  echo '<option value="'.$data[0].'">' .$data[0]. '</option>';
} 
?>
```

2.

```
<?php
$res = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
while($data = mysql_fetch_row($res)):
?>
  <option value="<?php echo $data[0]; ?>"><?php echo $data[0]; ?></option>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Just choose the one that fits you best.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is this

```
<?php while { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $data[0];?>"><?php echo $data[0];?></option>
<?php } ?>
```